# updating data in external table

Tags: oracle, plsql

Lets assume the following scenario :
I have several users that will prepare .csv files (not being aware of each other so concurrency is possible).
The .csv file will always be in same format.
The data in the .csv file will contain a list of ids together with some other columns like update_date.
Based on that data i will create a procedure that will update data in real DB table.

The idea is to use external tables, to maximally simplify it for the .csv creators, so they will put files in a folder and stuff will be done for them, rest is my job.

The questions are :

1. Can i have several files as the source for 1 external table or i need 1 ext table for each file (and what i mean here is whenever there is new func call to load data from csv, it should be added to existing external table...so not all files are being loaded at once)
2. Can i update records/fields in external table.

Comment: For Question 1: You can load N no of .csv files into  one external  table so no need of 1 ext table for each file.                                                              Question:2 NO it is not possible to update an external table because the data will load into a table from a .csv file at the time of querying it.(select * from table).

Comment: I am talking about external table, not normal table

Comment: Have you read the documentation for this? Both answers are clearly in there.

Comment: I've read oracle docs and some blogs, and thus being confused, seeing external tables are writable but not updateable..im commin from MSSQL world so this is new for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

External table basically allowes to query the data stored in the external file(s). So from this point you can't issue an UPDATE on it.
You can

1) add new files in the directory and [ALTER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables013.htm) the table

```
ALTER TABLE my_ex  LOCATION ('file1.csv','file2.csv');
```

2) you can of course modify the existing files as well. There is no database state of the external table, each SELECT loads the data in the database, so you will always see the "updated" status.

** UPDATE **

An attempt to modify (e.g. UPDATE) leads to ORA-30657 operation not supported on external organized table.
To be able to maintain status in the database the data must be first copied in a regular table (CTAS - create table as select from the external table).

Comment: The link above points to 11g the [12c link](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/tables.htm#i1007591) interestingly doesn't provide the **ALTER LOCATION** statement, but I thing (hope) this is only documentation issue...

Comment: answer to 1 is what i needed, thanks, for 2 however, im asking is it possible to update it once i have it in external table, meaning programatically, not in source.